# Starting Services -- Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: java, directed-graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

The framework I'm working with consists of stateful services that have dependencies on other services, forming a directed acyclic graph http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph

I want to start the services as efficiently as possible.  This means starting services in parallel, where possible.  For example, in the graph on the wikipedia link.  I would start 3, 5, and 7 at the same time, since they don't have any dependencies.  I've seen topological sorts, but that alone doesn't tell you what can be started in parallel.  I'm looking for a library/api to group services, something like:

```
a
b, c, d,
e.
f, g,
h
```

Where this tells me to start "a" first, then "b", "c", and "d" in parallel, then "e", and so on.

I've found a few libraries that model Vertices, but nothing does the grouping I'm looking for.  So far I've found some implementations for directed graph, however, I need a permissive license (e.g. non gpl).  I've found ComputeNodeOrder http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/eclipse/osgi/internal/resolver/ComputeNodeOrder.Digraph.html (from equinox org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.2.R36x_v20110210), Jgrapht (lgpl) http://www.jgrapht.org/javadoc/, Jung http://jung.sourceforge.net/index.html, Plexus http://plexus.codehaus.org/plexus-utils/apidocs/org/codehaus/plexus/util/dag/DAG.html but not sure if any/all of these will do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a tree iterated using a breadth first search to me.  Each level has the services that can be started in parallel; later dependencies are further down in the tree.

Comment: yup, sounds pretty much like it, but if you wait for all services in one level to start, you miss an opportunity to go down one more level for independent paths (i.e. nodes that don't require any of the siblings to be started first).

Comment: It's not a tree since a service can be dependent on multiple services (i.e. multiple parents).